# JASIG Central Authentication Service 4, custom authentication and custom exception

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, jasig

i upgrading CAS from 3.5.2 to 4.

In version 3.5.2, i create a CustomAuthentication class  extends AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler to do my custom authentication and throw exception based i needs

example:

```
throw new BadCredentialsAuthenticationException("error.accountNotExist");
```

so in message.properties i just add error.accountNotExist=Account not exist.

then the front end will return the string above.

how ever in CAS version 4, AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler has changed. not support  BadCredentialsAuthenticationException anymore. So how to do it in cas version 4 in order to return any custom string that i want?

Comment: Easy, throw new AccountNotFoundException("Account not exist"), why is so important storing the message in a properties file?

Comment: because questions title is custom exception, means there are more than AccountNotFoundException, likes account inactive,account expired, account not enable now. but return message is generic "Invalid Credentials". In order to achieve that, custom authentication is needed. Perhaps u have more easier way to add custom exceptions?

Comment: Not, you got the better solution, but I still thinking why is so important displaying an ultra detailed message to the user, anyway, why not update the "authenticationFailure.AccountNotFoundException" to a more appropiate "Account Not Exist" instead of the inappropiate text "Invalid credentials"?

Comment: its just a example,i pick that just more easier to let ppl understand what i say. and i did change the message instead of "invalid credentials" and also added a lot custom exceptions :)

Answer (score 3):

since no 1 answer, and i try find out by my own.

steps to add custom exceptions

1 create new exceptions class extends LoginException

2 in messages.properties add corresponding message for new added exceptions

3 in login-webflow.xml --> handleAuthenticationFailure action-state add `<transition on="<yourCustomExcception>" to="generateLoginTicket"/>`

4 create a CustomAuthenticationExceptionHandler.java, copy original source code, and add new exception into  DEFAULT_ERROR_LIST

5 in cas-servlet.xml replace authenticationExceptionHandler to your CustomAuthenticationExceptionHandler